# How to update the cache in the background?

Tags: vuejs2, workbox

I'm starting in the PWA world with the workbox. I currently use the [vue-cli 3 tamplate for pwa](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa), which uses the workbox.

I configured all offline access:

```
pwa: {
  workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
  workboxOptions: {
    skipWaiting: true
  }
}
```

The only possibility of updating my cache is when I enter the site, the generated SW checks if there is an update and if it exists, it is enabled so that the next reload is activated.

But is there a possibility to do this in the background? When I send a push, ask the cache to be updated? Can anyone give any hints how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing most closely matches the idea behind [Periodic Background Sync](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md#periodic-synchronization-in-design), which would "wake" your service worker up at predefined intervals, and give it a chance to update itself.

Unfortunately, no browsers currently support Periodic Background Sync, and it appears to have stalled a bit in terms of getting standardized.

Note that while it is also possible to "wake" your service worker by using [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications), users have to explicitly accept notification permissions first, and you need to show a notification message each time your service worker "wakes up". You can't just silently trigger a `push` event handler without showing a notification. Therefore, attempting to replicate Periodic Background Sync via Push Notifications isn't a great idea.